# Combining results from multiple tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. One contains `members` and the other members `dogs`.

The `dogs` table contains a membership number which is what links it to the `members' table.

The `members` table contains all of the address information.

Every week, I have to select new paid registrations and send out cards.  So I need to combine details from the `dog` table with information from `member` and have it all on one row. Then I can export it and send it to our card printer.

What is the best way to do this? I have been playing with JOINS and just can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exporting to the printer I leave to you, but the `JOIN` is rudimentary.  Replace `membership_number` with the correct column name.

```
SELECT
  members.*,
  dogs.*
FROM
  members
  JOIN dogs ON members.membership_number = dogs.membership_number
```

The above is brief, but in practice it is usually better to explicitly name all columns in the `SELECT` list, especially when you have the same named column in both tables of the join.

```
SELECT
  members.membership_number,
  members.address,
  members.state,
  members.someothercolumn,
  dogs.name,
  dogs.breed,
  dogs.someotherdogcolumn
FROM
  members
  JOIN dogs ON members.membership_number = dogs.membership_number
```

The [MySQL `JOIN` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) has many examples which can guide you in future queries.

Comment: That Worked like a charm.   Thank you very much.   I am brand new to programming so this is all pretty cool to me still :)